# Are you really supposed to put three copies of an image in a Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#Embedded_Images

Am I doing something wrong or is there no way to add just one image in the Xamarin.Forms project instead of an image in the project for each platform? This doesn't work.

```
myImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("MyProject.myImage.jpg"); // yes, build action embedded resource
```

In fact, adding that line will cause a runtime error before it even hits that line. But enough with worrying about silly things like that.

How do you add the image ONE time with Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This method means that each platform won't be able to load different image resolutions; this will have to be implemented manually. This method may also cause app download size to be larger.

You can include images just once in your projects as embedded resources.

Then use the following to load it from that assembly.

```
var assemblyOfMyProject = typeof(MyProject.SomeClassInThisAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
ImageSource.FromResource("MyProject.myImage.jpg", assemblyOfMyProject);
```

> Including the assembly may not be neccessary as of NetStandard 2.0.

Here is a handy extension method to use on a string, it stores the assembly so you only load that once.

```
public static class ImageSourceExtensions
{
    private static Assembly _assembly;

    static ImageSourceExtensions()
    {
        _assembly = typeof(MyProject.SomeClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    }

    public static ImageSource FromResource(this string path)
    {
        return ImageSource.FromResource(path, _assembly);
    }
}
```

Use like so

`ImageSource image = "MyProject.image.jpg".FromResource();`

Comment: But have in mind that it totally makes sense to have the Image multiple times, since iOS and Android select the right one (mdpi etc.) in terms of the devices resolution! If you are doing it right you will have more than three "copies"

Comment: Fun fact is that in 2019 Google is going to introduce app bundling which means that they will be converting apk to several different apks depending on the resoruce resoultion and architecture type - [see more here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9D63S4ZRBls). Thus, providing several different resolutions will help to reduce app size on user device.

Comment: I'd say that SVG format is the future; SVG doesn't carry any of the sizing issues associated with traditional bitmap formats, as it's rendered to scale, of course this carries it's own performance penalty.

Support for SVG in all platforms is increasing, and once SVG animations are supported, it'll be even more customisable.